# EEEtran BibTeX Style - how to activate journal name in the reference?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I use the IEEEtran to edit the papers, but the journal name won't show in the reference, only like
" [1] F. Basile, F. Caccavale, P. Chiacchio, J. Coppola, and C. Curatella,“Task-oriented motion planning for multi-arm robotic systems,” vol. 28,no. 5, pp. 569–582."
How can I solve this?

thank you very much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A MWE **with bibliography** ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)) would be great.

Comment: Which entry type do you use for the Basile et al publication?

Comment: After checking the .bib file, I found that the journal name is named as "journaltitle", and I changed "journaltitle" to "journal", the journal names can be generated in the bibliography. However, the .bib file is created automatically.
Afterall, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Using Google Scholar I have found this article. Here is BibTeX database record:

```
  @article{basile2012task,
  title={Task-oriented motion planning for multi-arm robotic systems},
  author={Basile, F and Caccavale, F and Chiacchio, P and Coppola, J and Curatella, C},
  journal={Robotics and Computer-Integrated Manufacturing},
  volume={28},
  number={5},
  pages={569--582},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Please check how its differs from your record.
And here is an example. After processing this file (pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{basile2012task,
  title={Task-oriented motion planning for multi-arm robotic systems},
  author={Basile, F and Caccavale, F and Chiacchio, P and Coppola, J and Curatella, C},
  journal={Robotics and Computer-Integrated Manufacturing},
  volume={28},
  number={5},
  pages={569--582},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{basile2012task}    

\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\end{document}
```

I have got proper citation:

[1] F. Basile, F. Caccavale, P. Chiacchio, J. Coppola, and C. Curatella,
“Task-oriented motion planning for multi-arm robotic systems,” *Robotics
and Computer-Integrated Manufacturing*, vol. 28, no. 5, pp. 569–582,
2012.

Comment: But if I use ieeetran, the journal name can not be shown. Thx

Answer (score 1):

From the usage instructions inside `IEEEfull.bib`

> USAGE:
>
> ```
> \bibliographystyle{mybstfile}
> \bibliography{IEEEfull,mybibfile}
> ```
>
> where the IEEE titles in the .bib database entries use the strings
>   defined here. e.g.,
>
> `journal = IEEE_J_AC,`
>
> to yield "{IEEE} Transactions on Automatic Control"

If the journal of your article does not jet have a predefined expansion to its full name, you can add one yourself to your .bib file, for example:

```
@STRING{IEEE_J_STSP       = "{IEEE} Journal of Selected Topics in Signal Processing"}
```